# kendo ui data bind enabled change not tracked MVVM

Tags: data-binding, kendo-ui

I'm trying to enable a button only after I have received a response from a request I send, after some conditions are met.

So in my template I have:

`<a data-role="button" class="confirmbutton autobutton" data-icon="action" data-bind="events: { click: onConfirmClick }, enabled: canConfirm">Confirm</a>`

`canConfirm` is a boolean of the `viewModel`.
So at some point in my callback I set `viewModel.canConfirm = true` and can see that indeed the property has changed to `true`, but this doesn't enable the button.

Why? How can I enable the button programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.

You need to set the `viewModel` properties with a function *in it's declaration*. I know I'm not explaining it well, so:

I called `viewModel.enableConfirmButton(shouldEnable);` from inside my callback, and then `enableConfirmButton` inside the viewModel is:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable($.extend({}, initialModel, {

//...

enableConfirmButton: function (shouldEnable) {
    this.set("canConfirm", shouldEnable);
    this.set("canCheck", !shouldEnable);
},

//...
```

Comment: Or you could have done viewModel.set("canConfirm", true) in your callback. The key is using the 'set' function on the viewmodel to change its properties which fires the change event that causes any bindings to update.